# Does piwik have a length limit to the url it's tracking?

Tags: url, analytics, matomo

I've been successfully using piwik and I was wondering if there is a length limit to the url piwik is currently tracking. I'm asking this because I have some download links that need tracking and they can reach some pretty big lengths. They do not seem to be tracked by piwik.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some [url length limits](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) depending on the browser - also, check to see what is the maximum length of the URL that can be stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Long URLs should still be tracked, but will be truncated after 1024 characters by default. This can be customised: https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_21239/
But even if URLs exceed the length, they should still be tracked (truncated).